# ignore_const_cols missing values

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, h2o

In the h2o models that have the "ignore_const_cols" parameter, how is "constant" determined with respect to missing values?

i.e if a column has only one unique non-missing value and also some missing values, and "ignore_const_cols" is selected, will no splits occur on this column to separate the missing values from the one constant value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy enough to test this

R code:

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
iris_data<-as.data.frame(iris)
iris_data$Petal.Width<-1
iris_data[iris_data$Species=='setosa','Petal.Width']<-NA
iris_h2o<-as.h2o(iris_data)
h2o.gbm(training_frame=iris_h2o,y='Species')
iris_data$Petal.Width<-as.factor(iris_data$Petal.Width)
iris_h2o<-as.h2o(iris_data)
h2o.gbm(training_frame=iris_h2o,y='Species')
```

Regardless of if the constant column with missing values is numeric or factor, the same warning is given:

```
Warning message:
In .h2o.startModelJob(algo, params, h2oRestApiVersion) :
  Dropping constant columns: [Petal.Width].
```

Therefore the answer to your question appears to be that h2o ignores missing values when determining if a column is constant